# How do I create a grav form without a corresponding page

Tags: php, html, forms, grav

I have a contact form in my footer which will be displayed on all pages. How do I do that? The documentation thinks that I always have one specific page responsible for the form.
The form currently looks like this in twig:

```
        <form method='POST'>
            <label for='name'>{{ "o.footer.form.name"|t }}</label>
            <input type='text' id='name' name='name' required='required'/>
            <label for='email'>{{ "o.footer.form.email"|t }}</label>
            <input type='text' id='email' name='email'/>
            <label for='phone'>{{ "o.footer.form.phone"|t }}</label>
            <input type='tel' id='phone' name='phone'/>
            <label for='message'>{{ "o.footer.form.message"|t }}</label>
            <textarea id='message' name='message'></textarea>
            <input type='submit' value="{{ "o.footer.form.submit"|t }}"/>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that since the latest release of [Form plugin](https://github.com/getgrav/grav-plugin-form).

Just create a page with a form defined and then call it from other page, example:

```
{% include "forms/form.html.twig" with {form: forms( {route: '/newsletter-signup'} ) } %}
```

More information: https://learn.getgrav.org/forms/forms#displaying-forms-in-page-content

Comment: Thank you! The page should/could be named `form/default.md` and instead of defining the route, you can just call it by name.

Comment: I’m confronted with something similar and thought about using the _user/config/site.yaml_ file to add a form `form-contact`.

I then call this form from my base.html.twig template with `{% include 'forms/form.html.twig' with {form: site.forms['form-contact']} %}` but I wonder if that’s a bad practice.

Comment: So then are what folks doing to tackle this is creating a form page that is non-visible? True you could just have the form in one arbitrary page's frontmatter, but it would be nice to just have the form somewhere unique. However, I'm not sure @arkhi 's idea is good practice.